# heroku pg:psql keeps connecting but nothing happens afterwards

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm new to Heroku and I've noticed that their page provides a tutorial on NodeJS where they go step by step on how to integrate a project or start a new project on their platform. Through the last step there's a section for databases, using postgres as an example, which happens to be the database type I'm looking to integrate in my project as well. However, after following through with the tutorial, I noticed that when executing `heroku pg:psql`, the Git Bash (what I used) keeps showing Connecting to [...] (the name of the database) and nothing else happens, effectively not allowing me to create rows and whatnot in the database so I can see them as part of the application. Have I gone wrong somewhere, or am I just missing something?

I have tried multiple ways to make sure it's connecting to the right database, I have even made a new database, however nothing works and the process keeps going endlessly. I've let it run for more than a day and still goes nowhere.

According to this source, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database, I should be connected to it with that bit of code there, however the only thing that I'm shown is `--> Connecting to postgresql-animate-97685` .

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same mistake and could not find a solution. I spent a lot of time to understand what needs to be done for this.
As a result, as I decided:
I originally used the console from Git Bash. Instead, I tried using the standard console from Windows - cmd. And it all worked out as per the instructions from Heroku.
By the way, this is not the first time that Git Bash fails me.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I ended up taking another route completely in the end. I decided to go with the **Heroku Postgres** add-on and I just connected to it with pgAdmin and now I have full control over what's going on in there. However, it's good to know there's an alternative solution in case I stumble upon the same situation in the future. I didn't expect Git Bash to fail me as hard as it did...Thank you nonetheless!